# How to change the color property of boundary vertices of a mesh in CGAL

Tags: colors, cgal

I have a `halfedge_descriptor` boundary on a PolyMesh which I need to mark in another color (say Red). Assume that the file stream `in` is the file containing mesh in off, without any color property. Here is the part of CGAL code:

```
    typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>                           Kernel;
    typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>                               PolyMesh;
    PolyMesh sm;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<PolyMesh>::halfedge_descriptor       halfedge_descriptor;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<PolyMesh>::vertex_descriptor         vertex_descriptor;

    in >> fs;
    halfedge_descriptor bhd = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::longest_border(sm).first;
    BOOST_FOREACH(vertex_descriptor ved, CGAL::vertices_around_target(bhd,sm)) 
    {
    // Need to do something here
    }
```

I am not sure what has to be done in the iterator block, so that I can change the color property of the vertices which are on the boundary `bhd`.

Comment: What do you mean "color" ? Can't you just draw the vertices in a different color than the others ? Or do you need an internal property that holds a specific color ? I don't understant what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to color the border vertices to another color say for eg. Red

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough information about what you are trying to do, because what you are showing is an empty Polyhedron with no color property, so none of its vertices have any color.What I usually do is feed the Polyhedron information to my drawing API, (I use OpenGL) by iterating the edges, and give another color for border edges. But it is not CGAL that does that, it is OpenGL.

Comment: I am really sorry, I have clarified my question further. I hope now I am able to convey my doubt.

Comment: I still don't know if you are trying to draw the polyhedron, in which case it is your OpenGL code that you need to change, or if you are trying to write another OFF file with the color, in which case you need to write your own function that writes COFF and that CGAL does not provide.